# Including a subdirectory in an Excluded parent directory

Tags: google-custom-search

I have a directory in my site I wish to show up in the search results, but its parent directory is excluded.

For example i have excluded www.example.com/test/ but i wish to include the directory www.example.com/test/indexme/.

So how can i include a sub directory of an excluded parent?

Currently i have included the directory www.example.com/test/indexme* (selecting "Include just this specific page....") but because the parent directory www.example.com/test is EXCLUDED, when i test in search bar on the rigtht of the CSE page the directory www.example.com/test/indexme/ is not shown in the search results.

If i remove the excluded parent (www.example.com/test/) from the excluded list, i can see search results in my test, but now will other directories in www.example.com/test/ be indexed, which  I dont want?

Many thanks